# Why does JDBC work on my computer, but not on my friends'?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, driver

We have a database on a server for our project.
When I run the program, it works completely fine. I can log in, and register another account.
But when my classmate runs the code, he gets an exception: `No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://ServerIp//DBName`

My code looks like this:

```java
String hostURL = "jdbc:mysql://ServerIp:3306/Database"; //There's an actual ip of course
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(hostURL, "username", "password");
System.out.println("Connected successfully");
```

We've already added `mysql-connector` to the dependencies (IntelliJ), but it didn't help at all.
Also, I didn't even need to add it, the project worked just fine for me without doing anything at all. The project is in Java Enterprise -> Web Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs if JDBC is not able to find a suitable driver for
the URL format passed to the getConnection()
method e.g."jdbc:mysql://" in our case.

In order to solve this error,
you need the MySQL JDBC driver like
"mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar" in your classpath.

Or because you forgot to register your mysql jdbc driver with the java application.

```
Connection con = null;
try {
    //registering the jdbc driver here, your string to use 
    //here depends on what driver you are using.
    Class.forName("something.jdbc.driver.yourdriver");   
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(hostURL, ...);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: In modern Java, JDBC drivers are automatically registered via the Java [*Service Provider Interface (SPI)*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) facility. No need for `Class.forName`.